# backgroundworker loop to read from telnet - C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Fairly new to programming but need this code to get some hardware I am building working.

I am writing a c# program to connect to a telnet server and read from the feed then display in a text box (sounds simple enough)...

A connect button connects the telnet and runs a backgroundworker that then waits for the telnet session to send data and then outputs to the text box in the complete section of the background worker.

My question is, how then do I get the background worker to run again once that read is received?

If i use a whil loop in the connect button that encapsulates the backgroundworker starter then the ui freezes up (which was the whole point of using a background worker to start with).

THanks for your help.

Shags

Comment: EDIT: I would consider moving away from a backgroundworker and into the Task Parallel Library.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you're reading from the telnet server.

I wouldn't recommend using a `BackgroundWorker` or even a `Task` for this. You can have your GUI code create a [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) instance. Once that's created, the button handler calls `BeginConnect`, passing a reference to the function that will be called when the connection is made.

When the connection callback is called, it gets the stream (calls `GetStream`), and calls `BeginRead`on the stream. And the read handler calls `BeginRead` again. So what you end up with is an asynchronous loop.

See the examples for [BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145193.aspx) and [EndConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.endconnect.aspx), and the `NetworkStream` [BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.endconnect.aspx) and `EndRead` methods.

Also, you might get some good information from a search for [TcpClient asynchronous example].

Comment: Hi, I am using the Minimilistic Telnet library (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library)